Every other entry of FFT comes back negative of what I expect when doing the math by hand
I'm working with an example signal x = [4, 3, 5, 10, 5, 3]. In fftshift land, this is an even signal, because the indices n go [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2].
I know I should be able to find
$$a_k = \sum_{n=-3}^2 x[n] e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$$
where N = 6, because that's the length of the signal, and x[n] and n come from the above.
If I do it out analytically, I get
$$4 e^{-j\frac{\pi}{3}(-3)k} + 3 e^{-j\frac{\pi}{3}(-2)k} + 5 e^{-j\frac{\pi}{3}(-1)k} + 10 e^0 + 5 e^{-j\frac{\pi}{3}k} + 3 e^{-j\frac{\pi}{3}2k}$$
$$= 10 + 10\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}k) + 6\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3}k) + 4(-1)^k$$
Then if I plug in $k \in \{0, ... N-1\}$, I get 30, 8, 6, 2, 6, 8.
Just to make sure I did my math right, I made a python script to implement to above, and I get the same thing:
import numpy

x = [4, 3, 5, 10, 5, 3]
ns = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]

def A(k):
    a_k = 0
    for i,n in enumerate(ns):
        a_k += x[i] * numpy.exp(-2*numpy.pi/len(x) * 1j * n * k)
    return a_k

for k in range(0, len(x)):
    print("k =", k, ":", A(k))

prints:
k = 0 : (30+0j)
k = 1 : (8.000000000000002-4.440892098500626e-16j)
k = 2 : (6+8.881784197001252e-16j)
k = 3 : (2-1.4695761589768238e-15j)
k = 4 : (6.000000000000001+1.7763568394002505e-15j)
k = 5 : (7.999999999999985-2.6645352591003757e-15j)

But if I call numpy.fft.fft([4, 3, 5, 10, 5, 3]), I get back [30, -8, 6, -2, 6, -8]. Why is every other element negated? Is this a quirk of the FFT algorithm? According to the numpy documentation, their code should be doing the same math I implemented above.

I see what's going on. The FFT doesn't use the n vector as I've defined above. It uses n = [0, ... N-1]. If I use that instead, I get the alternating negatives the way numpy returns. I can't work it out analytically as easily, but the code proves it works out.

The DFT is typically defined from $[0…N-1]$ so the signal is centered in the DFT window. However, you can compute it for indexes outside that range by doing a variable substitution, which should just result in a phase shift.

The DFT of a signal is complex , i.e. it has a magnitude and a phase. If the time domain signal is symmetric, i.e. $x[-n] = x[n]$ than the phase is zero. That's what you got (correctly) with your manual computation.
It follows also directly from the definition that both time and frequency domain signals are periodic with the DFT length $N$, i.e. $x[n] = x[n+mN], m \in \mathbb{Z}$.
The standard definition of the DFT that Python follows is
$$X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}  x[n] e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}} $$
It starts indexing at 0 so the indices "go" [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Because of the periodicity properties that is equivalent to [0, 1, 2, -3, -2, -1], so the vector you passed into the Python FFT is a circularly shifted version of the one you did by hand.
A circular shift in the time domain corresponds to a linear phase shift in the frequency domain, i.e.
$$x[n-n_0] \leftrightarrow  X[k]e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn_0}{N}}$$
In your case the shift is 3 samples so the phase factor comes out to be
$$P[k] = e^{-j2\pi\frac{3k}{6}} = e^{-j\pi k} = -1^{k} = [1,-1,1,-1 ...] $$
which happens to alternate between 1 and -1.

In fftshift land

Neither Python or Matlab has a native means of operating in what you call fftshift land. You need to manage this manually.
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
x = np.array([4, 3, 5, 10, 5, 3])
N = x.size
X1 = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(np.fft.fftshift(x)))
print(X1)


I like the math explanation with P[k].
